# Mover projeto do git para workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, ubuntu, github

usando o eclipse eu clonei meu repositório do github no diretório `/home/douglas/git`. Meu repositório chama `X` e dentro dele que está meu projeto `Y`.Quando vou importar o projeto no eclipse eu gostaria de que o mesmo fosse movido para o workspace do eclipse. isso é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o clone por meio da ferramenta EGit dentro do eclipse. Será mais simples. No passo a passo será perguntado se você deseja importar o projeto.

Comment: Mas é isso mesmo, o padrão que ele sugere é em /home/douglas/git. Mas quando fosse importar ele podia ir pra dentro do workspace.